# Add option for Vendors to upload video in Product form for Dokan Multivendor Plugin

Tags: vendor, dokan

We would like to add option for Vendors to upload video in Product form for Dokan Multivendor Plugin. As i am not pretty expert with coding knowledge can anyone tell me how can we achieve this?

Tried nothing till now but would like the option for vendors to upload product video